# Check if notifications are allowed for the app

Tags: winforms, winapi

I've created a background WinForms app that runs on Windows 10. The app uses `NotifyIcon` to create an icon in the taskbar, and calls `ShowBalloonTip` to display a notification for the user. It works, but there are many ways notifications can be disabled/suppressed for the application.

This setting can be checked by looking at the *Notifications & actions* screen.

[image]

Given that the main purpose of my application is to display a notification to the user, so what I want is upon app initialization, to check if notifications are *on*.

I don't expect such API to be available as a managed API, so I'm tagging this "winapi".

Comment: This interface is way to new to provide a Win32 API. If this information is exposed at all, you'd have to go looking into the Windows Runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Those settings are for the user to customize how the OS behaves, not for how your app behaves. If your app wants to issue a notification, then it should just issue a notification unconditionally, and let the OS display it to the user (or not) according to the user's current settings (which can be changed while your app is running). There is no API your app can call to check what settings the user has specified.